# Android implement on list item click to pass data to new Activity via custom list adapter

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development, i have tried by checking through others sample codes and i managed to pull data from my website to custom listview, my Main Activity shows this:
[Main Activity Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj5Rx.png)
currently, i am showing few text on description, i want if i click on list item, `jobid` will be taken to new Activity in my case is Main2Activity. My Problem is: i don't know where to implement on list item click event and how can i write it so it can pass `jobid` to Main2Activity. My Full MainActivity class source codes are as follows.

```
package com.helloworld.kazitz.mnewonluine;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.helloworld.kazitz.mnewonluine.models.KaziModel;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvData;
    private ListView lvKazi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvKazi = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvKazi);

        new JSONTask().execute("http://johnapps.ga/kazitz/kazitz.php");
    }


    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<KaziModel>> {

        @Override
        protected List<KaziModel> doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                String finalJson = buffer.toString();

                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("kazitz");

                List<KaziModel> kaziModelList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    KaziModel kaziModel = new KaziModel();
                    kaziModel.setId(finalObject.getInt("id"));
                    kaziModel.setTime(finalObject.getString("time"));
                    kaziModel.setDomain(finalObject.getString("domain"));
                    kaziModel.setTitle(finalObject.getString("title"));
                    kaziModel.setSdesc(finalObject.getString("sdesc"));
                    kaziModelList.add(kaziModel);
                }
                return kaziModelList;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                if(connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if(reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<KaziModel> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            KaziAdapter adapter = new KaziAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
            lvKazi.setAdapter(adapter);
            // TODO need to set data to the list
        }
    }



    public class KaziAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

        private List<KaziModel> kaziModelList;
        private int resource;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public KaziAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<KaziModel> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            kaziModelList = objects;
            this.resource = resource;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final int jobid = kaziModelList.get(position).getId();

            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            }

            TextView tvSource;
            TextView tvDate;
            TextView tvTitle;
            TextView tvExcerpt;

            tvSource = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSource);
            tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvExcerpt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvExcerpt);

            tvSource.setText(kaziModelList.get(position).getDomain());
            tvDate.setText(kaziModelList.get(position).getTime());
            tvTitle.setText(kaziModelList.get(position).getTitle());
            tvExcerpt.setText(kaziModelList.get(position).getSdesc());

            return convertView;
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            new JSONTask().execute("http://johnapps.ga/kazitz/kazitz.php");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your onCreate right after where `lvKazi=...` line:

```
lvKazi.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //do what you are trying to do here
        }
    });
```

Comment: how can i pass jobid because my main intention is to reuse jobid value in another activity..

Comment: The callback gives you the position of the item within the list array (kaziModelList). From there you should be able to get the specific item by kaziModelList.get(position) and from there the jobid, right?

Comment: Can you please provide me sample code as you did above, only to get jobid in 'onItemClick' . I am not experienced on android i have just started making android apps.